# How to redirect to a new page and show a modal there by clicking on a button that is in the previous page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="submit2" value="Finish Recording">
```

What I am aiming to do is when the button is clicked, it redirects to another page, and when the redirected page is loaded, the modal should appear in the new page.

I know I can do all of this easily with multiple buttons but that's not what I'm looking for, I have even tried a sleep function which didn't work.

JS :

```
$('#submit2').on('click', function (e) {

  location.href = "bot.net";

  $('#myModal2').modal('show');

});
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Display the modal on the *target page*, not on *this page*.

Comment: You could add a query string to the button link and then have javascript check for that on load. If it's there then show the modal.

Answer (score 2):

Make the modal on the page you want to display

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From the first page where the form submission is happening

JS :

```
$('#myForm').on('click', function (e) {
  location.href = "bot.net?showModel=1";
});
```

On the bot.net page on document ready check for the GET element and store it in another variable

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if(showModel == 1){
       $('#myModal2').modal('show');
  }
})
```